# Having Trouble with RewriteRule syntax and configuration, challenging

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm really struggling with the syntax of a Rewrite Rule. I'm hoping you can help.

I used a node package module to create a bunch of html snapshots of a super ajaxy site. The module outputs the snapshots in a diretory named as the URL for later use with escape_fragment rewrite rules. So exampledomain.net/a45.php?lang=eng is output as ./snapshots/a45.php?lang=eng/index.html. So to cd into that directory I have to of course escape the special characters.

I am attempting to Rewrite http://testdomain.net/a45.php?lang=eng to http://testdomain.net/snapshots/a45.php?lang=eng/index.html and I cannot get my rewrite rules to work.

Here's the syntax I've tried:
in an .htaccess file in the subdirectory

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
ReWriteBase /var/www/vhosts/testdomain.net/httpdocs/secure/clients/amg/3dot0
RewriteRule ^a45\.php?lang=eng$ /snapshots/a45.php?lang=eng/index.html
```

I have also tried it with and without RewriteBase.
I've also tried the same as above with the second url escaped and with a couple different characters on the first url ALL to no avail...
OH and I was sure to enable Allowoverride all on the entire httpdocs directory as well in the main vhost.conf file -- I know that directive is working becuase Options +Indexes allows me to browse directories throughout this tree.

Any advice or clues are appreciated greatly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Directory names including characters ? = / are not going to be liked. Try to avoid them.
2. The purpose of a rewrite is to run *another* page from somewhere else, not dump something into a new directory. Is that what you're trying to do? You're telling the server than there is an index.html to run, in /snapshots/a45.php?lang=eng/ directory.
3. A RewriteRule isn't going to see the Query String anyway (?lang=eng). The ? is telling it that the p is optional.

Comment: something like RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(\w+)=(\w+)$
RewriteRule ^/path /path/%1/%2?

Comment: You can check what's in the QUERY STRING, and maybe even grab it from RewriteCond, but be careful about using anything with odd characters that could confuse the server's operating system, such as ?, &, =, /.  What exactly are you trying to do here? Are you going to run a specific index.html based upon what's in the QS, or are you trying to dump something into a new directory?

Comment: I am using a node.js script that calls a node package module called html-snapshots which uses phantomJS to serialize a bunch of html pages. I want to redirect our custom search spider to those snapshots for one indexing session. I started trying to rename the directories with Perl and that didn't work out. I also tried using a regex function to change the way the node package module outputs these directories and ALMOST got it but not quite. I tried executing the Perl script like so: find . -exec ./rename.pl \;

Comment: This is the Perl script: `#!/usr/bin/perl 
foreach $name ( @ARGV )  { 
    $newname = $name; 
    $newname =~ tr/!/-/; 

    $newname =~ s/%25/%/g; 
    $newname =~ s/%20/-/g; 
    $newname =~ s/%5B/[/g; 
    $newname =~ s/%5D/]/g; 
    $newname =~ s/%2B/+/g; 
    $newname =~ s/%3F/?/g; 
    $newname =~ s/%3D/=/g; 
    $newname =~ s/%26/&/g; 
    $newname =~ s/%40/@/g; 

    $newname =~ s/_/-/g; 
    $newname =~ s/ /-/g; 
    $newname =~ s/,//g; 
   

#    print "$name becomes $newname\n"; 
#    print "$newname\n"; 

   rename ($name, temp); 
   rename (temp, $newname); 
}`